# R which items in one column are higher than in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 columns in a data frame with 15.000 entries.

```
col1   col2
mike   anna
eve    charly
george mike
jenn   george
```

I would like to find out, which entries in Col1 are a certain amount higher than in Col2.

I already have a solution where I loop thru each entry in Col1 and check it's position in Col2, but with 15.000 in takes ages:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){  
    myposinCol2 <- grep(df[i,1], df[,2])
    if(myposinCol2[1] > (i + 500)){ #take it }
 }
```

Could someone point me in a direction to improve this?

Thx
Joerg

Comment: `which(df[,1] == "george")`?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous; I think you mean you want to compare each name's ranks in col1 and col2.

Comment: What is the expected result? Values/rank for individual name that are common to both columns?

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is very simple - if this is what you're looking for:

```
df[which(df$col1 + 500 == df$col2),]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What are you doing here exactly? `df$col1` is a `character` column, which does not really allow to add `500` to it.

Comment: I know, but as seen in the question user987875 wants to get the lines which fulfill the following condition: 
if(myposinCol2[1] > (i + 500)){ #take it }

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr solution to compute the distance between the rank of each names in col1 and col2.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
add_rownames(d) %>% 
  gather(key, name, -rowname) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(key) %>% 
  summarise(diff=as.numeric(first(rowname)) - as.numeric(last(rowname)))
```

Then, if you want only names which appear 500 ranks later in col2:

```
%>% filter(diff < -500)
```